# duplicate browserHistory react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I have a problem with the following code:
This code what it does is when typing up or down I change the path, and it works fine, but the problem is that every time it changes it doubles the browser, and causes the web page to be blocked

```
function homeChange(e){

  $(window).keydown(function(event) { 
    if(event.which==40){
      browserHistory.push('/aplicaciones_moviles');
      console.log(browserHistory)
    }
  });
}
function appServiceChange(){
  $(window).keydown(function(event) { 
    if(event.which==40){
      console.log(browserHistory)
      browserHistory.push('/software_medida');
    }else if(event.which==38){
      browserHistory.push('/aplicaciones_moviles');
      console.log(browserHistory)
    }
  });

}
function softwareServiceChange(){
  $(window).keydown(function(event) { 
    if(event.which==40){
      console.log(event)
      browserHistory.push('/portafolio');
    }else if(event.which==38){
      browserHistory.push('/aplicaciones_moviles');
    }
  });
}

function portafolioChange(){
  $(window).keydown(function(event) { 
    if(event.which==40){
      console.log(event)
      browserHistory.push('/');
    }else if(event.which==38){
      browserHistory.push('/software_medida');
    }
  });
}

export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path='/' component={HomeLayout} onEnter={homeChange} >
          <IndexRoute component={HomeComponent} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='aplicaciones_moviles' component={AppServiceLayout} onEnter={appServiceChange} >
          <IndexRoute  />
        </Route>
        <Route path='software_medida' component={softwareServiceLayout} onEnter={softwareServiceChange}>
          <IndexRoute  />
        </Route>        
        <Route path='portafolio' component={portafolioLayout} onEnter={portafolioChange}>
          <IndexRoute  />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' component={HomeLayout}>
          <IndexRoute component={NotFoundComponent} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be adding event listeners when a route enters, but they are not being removed when the route leaves. This will mean that you have multiple listeners reacting to the `keydown` event.

You should make the event function non-anonymous and add an `onLeave` hook to the routes.

```
function portafolioEvent(event) { 
  if(event.which==40){
    console.log(event)
    browserHistory.push('/');
  } else if(event.which==38){
    browserHistory.push('/software_medida');
  }
}

function addPortafolioListener() {
  $(window).on('keydown', portafolioEvent);
}

function removePortafolioListener() {
  $(window).off('keydown', portafolioEvent);
}

<Route
  path='portafolio'
  component={portafolioLayout}
  onEnter={addPortafolioListener}
  onLeave={removePortafolioListener} />
```